# Backbone.js model.save() function unsuccessful

Tags: php, rest, backbone.js

I am newbie at Backbone and REST api. Here is my save function code:

```
 this.model.save(this.model.attributes, 
        {
            success: function (model) {
                app.menuItems.add(model);
                app.navigate('/w/backbone/', {trigger: true});
            }
        }
    );
```

and here is my model:

```
 var MenuItem = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
urlRoot: '/w/backbone/rest/items',
idAttribute: 'taskId',
defaults: {                         
    category: 'Entreés',
    imagepath: 'no-image.jpg',
    name: ''
}
 });
```

and here is my restful Api POST function :

```
 function items_post()
 {  
    // add an existing user and respond with a status/errors  
    $array=array(
                'item_id'=>$this->post('id'),
                'item_url'=>$this->post('url'),
                'item_name'=>$this->post('name'),
                'item_category'=>$this->post('category'),
                'imagepath'=>$this->post('imagepath')
        );
    $this->main_model->add_item($array);
 }
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

At the very least your API call needs to return the id of the newly created model and any attributes that were changed by the server.

Comment: I got my mistake! I haven't done two things! Everything was correct I just forgot to load model and another thing is that I didn't make Success response! That was really silly mistake of me! Anyways thank you for your support!